# Constant Crashes with Blender mostly from Materials

Tags: customization

Windows 7 Pro x64
Blender 2.74 - 2.75rc2

I'm curious if anyone else has had this error with Blender?

```
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Where is the violation coming from?

I've have been having a lot of issues with crashes since 2.73, and recently it has come down to this error alone. It usually happens when I'm selecting the material menu, creating a material, and even deleting meshes with materials.

I did reload to factory defaults, and created all new userprefs, and of course created a new startup file to go with it. Other issues I was having went away after that, but this one crashing issues still happens, and quite a lot.

Here's my [**startup file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2-k_tNVb4phYXpyTXJua2xveDg/view?usp=sharing) if anyone wants to look at it.

I've really cut down on the addons trying to track this down, but it doesn't seem to be related. There is nothing before the error, just a simple:

```
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

I'm hoping someone knows what this violation means, so that hopefully I can remedy this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be off topic as a bug and not an actual question, you might want to try BlenderArtists.org for questions like this. If you have enough rep, you can drop a link in the chat stream: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: Apparently with my startup file, you can simply click the "new" button under materials right after loading up, and 50% of the time it will crash.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise yeah, the reason I was posting here, was in case someone knew about this error in particular. I don't want to post it as a bug, since I'm not sure if it's just a setting or something. Even if someone was to give some information on how to get more information from my error, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Nevermind. It is obviously a bug. Reported it.